# Bootstrap navbar li active class without js

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the bootstrap official website navbar active class working without adding any jquery snippet. If someone clicks on "Base CSS" or any other button, "active" class removes from "home" button, page loads and active class added to that particular menu. 
Official link: [Click here.](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html)
All is happening without js.

I copied and paste their markup but it's no use. "home" button always has the "active" class.

Did I miss something?

Comment: This is because each page has the `active` class added to the `li` tag for that specific page. Open up **DevTools** and you'll see this.

Comment: You need to specify active class on each page to corresponding li tag

Comment: How they do that without javascript? What did they do?

Comment: There is no "page-name-class" generating inside body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to Bootstrap version 2.3.2, please get the latest version and try with that.

See used script by bootstrap site for making tabs active at this link: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js